# Using custom colormap on contourf

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contourf

I have created a colourmap 'mycmap' which I want to use on every contourf in Matlab. How do this?

I have tried

```
[C,h]=contourf(Xrange,Y_range,capacity,14,'LineColor',mycmap');
```

but it doesn't work. My custom colour scale looks like:

```
mycmap =

0.9725    0.9725    0.9725
0.9442    0.9442    0.9442
0.9159    0.9159    0.9159
0.8876    0.8876    0.8876
0.8593    0.8593    0.8593
0.8310    0.8310    0.8310
0.8027    0.8027    0.8027
0.8002    0.8002    0.8002
0.7976    0.7976    0.7976
0.7950    0.7950    0.7950
0.7924    0.7924    0.7924
0.7204    0.7204    0.7204
0.6484    0.6484    0.6484
0.6484    0.6484    0.6484
0.6484    0.6484    0.6484
0.6329    0.6329    0.6329
0.6175    0.6175    0.6175
0.6021    0.6021    0.6021
0.5885    0.5885    0.5885
0.5750    0.5750    0.5750
0.5615    0.5615    0.5615
0.5480    0.5480    0.5480
0.5345    0.5345    0.5345
0.5210    0.5210    0.5210
0.5075    0.5075    0.5075
0.4940    0.4940    0.4940
0.4564    0.4564    0.4564
0.4188    0.4188    0.4188
0.4092    0.4092    0.4092
0.3995    0.3995    0.3995
0.3899    0.3899    0.3899
0.3802    0.3802    0.3802
0.3706    0.3706    0.3706
0.3609    0.3609    0.3609
0.3512    0.3512    0.3512
0.3416    0.3416    0.3416
0.3328    0.3328    0.3328
0.3239    0.3239    0.3239
0.3151    0.3151    0.3151
0.3063    0.3063    0.3063
0.2974    0.2974    0.2974
0.2886    0.2886    0.2886
0.2798    0.2798    0.2798
0.2771    0.2771    0.2771
0.2743    0.2743    0.2743
0.2716    0.2716    0.2716
0.2689    0.2689    0.2689
0.2661    0.2661    0.2661
0.2634    0.2634    0.2634
0.2607    0.2607    0.2607
0.2580    0.2580    0.2580
0.2552    0.2552    0.2552
0.2525    0.2525    0.2525
0.2498    0.2498    0.2498
0.2471    0.2471    0.2471
0.2196    0.2196    0.2196
0.1922    0.1922    0.1922
0.1647    0.1647    0.1647
0.1373    0.1373    0.1373
0.1098    0.1098    0.1098
0.0824    0.0824    0.0824
0.0549    0.0549    0.0549
0.0275    0.0275    0.0275
     0         0         0
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you try searching with your preferred search engine? [matlab doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-fill-colors-for-contour-plot.html) knows many things ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke the colour map *after* the plotting...

```
[C,h]=contourf(Xrange,Y_range,capacity,14)
colormap(mycmap);
```